# I need an XSL transform to insert a child element of the selected node using data from an ancestor

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML looks like this:

```
<SCL>
  <IED name="D60_220SW1">
    <AccessPoint name="S1">
      <Server>
        <LDevice inst="Master">
          <LN0 lnClass="LLN0" inst="" lnType="LLN0_0">
            <ReportControl name="URCB01" rptID="XYZ" >
              <TrgOps dchg="true" />
              <OptFields configRef="true" />
             <RptEnabled max="1" />
            </ReportControl>
            <ReportControl name="URCB02" rptID="PAC" datSet="PAC" >
              <TrgOps dchg="true" qchg="true" period="true" />
              <OptFields configRef="true" />
             <RptEnabled max="1" />
            </ReportControl>
          </LN0>
        </LDevice>
      </Server>
    </AccessPoint>
  </IED>
</SCL>
```

I need a transform to select all `ReportControl` nodes where `@rptID="PAC"` and insert a child node of the `RptEnabled` node with attribute values dependent on the value of the name attribute of the `IED` ancestor node.

The result should look like this:

```
<SCL>
  <IED name="D60_220SW1">
    <AccessPoint name="S1">
      <Server>
        <LDevice inst="Master">
          <LN0 lnClass="LLN0" inst="" lnType="LLN0_0">
            <ReportControl name="URCB01" rptID="XYZ" >
              <TrgOps dchg="true" />
              <OptFields configRef="true" />
             <RptEnabled max="1" />
            </ReportControl>
            <ReportControl name="URCB02" rptID="PAC" datSet="PAC" >
              <TrgOps dchg="true" qchg="true" period="true" />
              <OptFields configRef="true" />
              <RptEnabled max="1" >
                <ClientLN iedName="APACC_1" apRef="S2" ldInst="LD0" lnClass="ITCI" lnInst="1" />
              </RptEnabled>
            </ReportControl>
          </LN0>
        </LDevice>
      </Server>
    </AccessPoint>
  </IED>
</SCL>
```

The values of the `iedName` and `apRef` attributes on the inserted `ClientLN` node are determined by the value of the name attribute on the `IED` ancestor node. Like this (I'm using C# pseudo code to illustrate):

```
iedName="APACC_" + name.Contains("_220") ? "1": "2"
```

I'm sure this is doable, but I can't figure out how, and I wasn't able to find an applicable example.

Comment: What does 'to select all ReportControl nodes where @rptID="PAC"' mean exactly, your example only has a single element with that attribute, do you simply want to transform any such element as described or do you need to group all such elements together? As for "I wasn't able to find an applicable example", I am sure any transformation example or in any XSLT tutorial using the identity transformation plus a template matching those elements can serve as a starting point so give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT does the job. But because you did not provide a rule for generating the other attributes of the `ClientLN` node, I (so far) just copied them from your desired output. It should be easy for you to fill them with the desired values.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">                       <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ReportControl[@rptID = 'PAC']">   <!-- replace special nodes -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::RptEnabled)]|@*" />
      <RptEnabled>
        <xsl:copy-of select="RptEnabled/@*" />
        <ClientLN apRef="S2" ldInst="LD0" lnClass="ITCI" lnInst="1">
          <xsl:attribute name="iedName">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="contains(ancestor::IED/@name,'_220')">APACC_1</xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>APACC_2</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </ClientLN>
      </RptEnabled>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You could simply write the template directly for `match="ReportControl[@rptID = 'PAC']/RptEnabled"`, there is no need to write one for the parent element as the identity transformation takes care of that.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.